# @RequestParam Map<String, String> Prints variable name as key in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

When I am trying to pass Map as RequestParam in spring boot, it prints variable name as key and complete value as a string. could anyone help why it's behaving strangely. my code snippet below

```
@PostMapping(value = "/", produces = MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
public String testController(@RequestParam Map<String, String> parms) throws Exception {
    parms.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println((k + ":" + v)));
    return "";
}
```

when I pass the value

> {"testkey":"testvalue"}

the out put it producing is parms : {"testkey":"testvalue"}

Comment: how are you sending the request and map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want to convert http request Body to a map, you should use **@RequestBody** instead of @RequestParam  on your params.
The RequestBody annotation will convert http request body to Object, while the RequestParam annotation will parse the http param(URL param or form field) to a method param.

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/", produces = MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
    public String testController(@RequestBody Map<String, String> parms) throws Exception {
        parms.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println((k + ":" + v)));
        return "";
    }
```

test your code using flowing *nix command

```
curl --request POST \
  --url http://localhost:9090 \
  --header 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"testkey":"testkey"}'
```

which will send follwing http request:

```
POST  HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9090
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

{"testkey":"testkey"}
```

Comment: Is there any way to pass multiple content type in same object i,e I want upload file a file and its meta data map, like below   public String updateEnityImage(@RequestBody Map<String, String> metaData, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) . how can I achieve this

Comment: @Anand you can use `upload(@RequestParam("file")MultipartFile multipartFile, @RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> allparams)`, and send your request with form data